# Compilation within cmake failed

Tags: cmake, ceph

I tried to compile the ceph project (https://ceph.io) by following all the advised command in their README.me

Unfortunately i'm getting this error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find verbs (missing: VERBS_LIBRARIES VERBS_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/Findverbs.cmake:13 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:156 (find_package)
```

I hope an cmake expert or any cmake advanced user can help me,

I tried to compile the ceph project (https://ceph.io) by following all the advised command in their README.me

Comment: On which distro you are building the project? E.g on Debian-based distros the script `install-deps.sh` should install [libibverbs-dev](https://github.com/ceph/ceph/blob/main/debian/control#L50) package, which provides headers and libraries missed according to the error message. You could also check whether given package (or similar one) is installed on your machine.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 20.04, i'll then try to install libibverbs manually.

Comment: So i installed it and it works and i have another library missing, do you know if there is a specific `install-deps.sh` i need to use for  ubuntu 20.04 distro ?